# Creating an GUI with PHP CLI

Tags: user-interface, php

Is there anyway to recreate the following interface in PHP using the PHP CLI on a bash shell?

If anyone could point me in the right direction - I'd be very grateful.

[image]

Comment: You'd probably use the ncurses library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That type of thing is usually, afaik,  done with [ncurses](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php)

Answer (score 5):

ncurses is probably your best bet: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.ncurses.php